# SSRS 2008, Two Datasets, One Chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, dataset, ssrs-2008-r2

I have two datasets. 
One `dataset1` has the fields `MonthNumber`, `MonthData`.
The other `dataset2` has the fields `MonthNumber`, `MonthBase`.
I want to use both the `MonthData` field and `MonthBase` fields in one dataset to create a chart.
Please help me if anyone has an idea how I can combine both datasets to one or use one field of one dataset into another?

Comment: How are the datasets being generated?  Are you able to edit the underlying query at all?

Comment: Jonnus thank you, the query for this data set is as follows:

Comment: Wow, what is that query trying to tell me?  Have you tried the above solution to get your desired output.  I don't need to see the entire query run, but I was interested in whether it was created as a Stored Procedure for example.  You should **edit** the above **question** with an example of the dataset that is being returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine the fields from two datasets without combining the datasets you need to use [the LOOKUP function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee210531.aspx).

To replicate this I created the datasets...

```
DataSet1
--------
MonthNumber  MonthData
------------ ----------
1            12
2            23
3            11
4            8

DataSet 2
---------
MonthNumber  MonthData
------------ ----------
1            10
2            15
3            20
4            25
```

1. Create a chart as you would normally for DataSet1.
2. Set the values to MonthData, and the Category Groups to MonthNumber
   Then add a new Series in the Values area, and set the expression to

   ```
    =Lookup(Fields!MonthNumber.Value, Fields!MonthNumber.Value, 
        Fields!MonthBase.Value, "DataSet2")
   ```

This effectively states join The ID fields DataSet1.MonthNumber, to DataSet2.MonthNumber, returning me DataSet2.MonthBase

The design will look like this

[image]

And the output like this

[image]

See also [the reference here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/42f86403-26d6-4129-85e9-7f0503618e41/join-dataset-in-ssrs) from which I derived this answer

Comment: Have you tried the above?  Have you had problems trying to implement it?  This answer matches the layout of the original question asked...

Comment: Thank you Jonnus....I have marked the questions as answered thank you. IN addition if I wanted to display a series of a calculation of MonthData/MonthBase as a percentage, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Just create a new series (again)and set the expression to be `=sum(Fields!MonthData.Value) / Lookup(Fields!MonthNumber.Value, Fields!MonthNumber.Value, Fields!MonthBase.Value, "DataSet2")`